# in c++ is this a good practice to initialize char array with string literal?

Tags: c++, string, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

in c++ is this a good practice to initialize char array with string?
such as:

```
char* abc = (char *) ("abcabc");
```

I see a lot of these in my co-worker's code. Should I change it to the right practice?
such as

```
std::string abc_str = "abcabc";
const char* abc= abc_str .c_str();
```

Comment: this is not the string but string literal actually.

Comment: I don't see a char array.

Comment: @T.C. you don't know c or cpp.

Comment: @BufBills Well, that's news to me.

Comment: I assure you @T.C. is more knowledgeable than you.

Comment: Your first example is bad because you're casting away constness from a string literal. Your second example is bad because if `abc_str` is modified, `abc` could be pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: Side note: Please do not cast a const string literal use: `const char* s = hello"` (the non const is deprecated)

Comment: as mentioned by buff its not the char array but pointer to the char

Comment: @T.C.: Technically the RHS is a (const) char array.  But you're right that `abc` isn't an array.

Comment: Just initialize with nullptr `s = nullptr` and leave std::string alone (it has a  default constructor). If you have a reasonable literal, use that.

Comment: @T.C. Don't mean to be pedantic but a string literal is a char array... ;)

Comment: @MooingDuck My apologies, I should have said "I don't see a char array being initialized."

Comment: I particularly like how there are three answers echoing "this is bad"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This statement

```
char* abc = (char *) ("abcabc");
```

is simply bad. String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So a valid declaration will look like

```
const char *abc = "abcabc";
```

Note: In C you indeed may write

```
char *abc = "abcabc";
```

Nevertheless string literals are immutable. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

By the way there is no any character array that is initialized by a string literal.:) Maybe you mean the following

```
char abc[] = "abcabc";
```

Using standard class `std::string` does not exclude using character arrays and moreover pointers to string literals.

Take into account that these declarations

```
const char *abc = "abcabc";
```

and

```
std::string abc_str = "abcabc";
const char* abc= abc_str .c_str();
```

are not equivalent. Relative to the first declaration string literals have static storage duration and their addresses are not changed during the program execution.
In the second declaration pointer `abc` points to dynamically allocated memory that can be reallocated if object `abc_str` will be changed. In this case the pointer will be invalid.

Also the first declaration supposes that the array (string literal) pointed to by the pointer will not be changed. In the second declaration it is supposed that the object of type std::string will be changed. Otherwise there is no great sense to declare an object of type std::string instead of the pointer.

Thus the meanings of the declarations are simply different.

Answer (score 7):

```
char* abc = (char *) ("abcabc");
```

That is bad. Don't do it.

You are treating a string literal that is not supposed to be modified like it can be modified.

After that,

```
abc[0] = 'd';
```

will be OK by the compiler but not OK at run time. What you need to use is:

```
char abc[] = "abcabc";
```

This will create an array that is modifiable.

Answer (score 4):

Both of those are bad.

```
char* abc = (char*) ("abcabc");
```

A string literal is a *constant* and, as such, may be stored in write protected memory. Therefore writing to it can crash your program, it is undefined behaviour.

Rather than cast away the *constness* you should keep it `const` and make a *copy* if you want to edit its contents.

```
const char* abc = "abcabc";
```

The other one should be avoided too:

```
std::string abc_str = "abcabc";
const char* abc = abc_str.c_str();
```

Keeping it const is good but if the string is changed it could be reallocated to another place in memory leaving your pointer dangling.

Also in pre `C++11` code the pointer stops being valid the second it is assigned because there is no guarantee it is not a temporary.

Better to call `abc_str.c_str()` each time.

The chances are that because `c_str()` is such a trivial operation it will be optimized away by the compiler making it just as efficient as using the raw pointer.

Instead of both of those what you *should* be doing is using `std::string` all the way. If you absolutely *need* a `const char*` (for old legacy code) you can obtain it using `c_str()`.

```
std::string abc_str = "abcabc"; // this is perfect why do more?

old_horrible_function(abc_str.c_str()); // only when needed
```